# how to count number of records from 3rd day to 62nd day for each person by using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, lead

[image]

I want to get the count of 'unitsold' for each Name from 3/1/2022 and 4/1/2022. For example Name 'a' required to count its units sold from 3rd to 8th day.

SQL query:

```
select Name, sum(unitsold) over (partion by Name order by Asc) from table1
```

The above query will provide units sold for the entire date range. But how to get sum of units sold **from 3rd day to 8th day** of each name?

Comment: You can use subquery or analytic sum with [Window Function Frame Specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html). In this case something like this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NAX83aYD).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name, sum (CASE when date >= '22/03/03' AND date <='22/03/08' then unitsold else 0 end) as totalUnitsSold
From table1 where 
Date >='22/03/01' and Date <='22/03/01'
Group by Name;
```

The case handles day logic and where clause handles the date range of 1 month.

Hope this helps, Thanks.

Comment: This is simplest query and limit to the date in where condition. I need to get the result for roll on basis. The where condition is for names exist in 22/03/01. But on the next day again some new names and units sold count from 22/03/03 to 22/03/08 and so on continuous for 6 months data. How the same logic applied for new names comes in next 6 months ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the query which gives the out put.